# How to invoke one function from another in PlantUML preprocessing?

Tags: uml, preprocessor, plantuml

I am using PlantUML and want to use the pre-processing feature.

I am getting an error when i try to call a return function from another returning function.
I don't know what I am doing wrong but I get an error. I bet it is something simple but I can't quite figure it out.

Here is the code.

```
@startuml
!$longestActivityLength = 20

!function $pmax($num1,$num2)
!if(num1 > num2){ return num1 }
!if(num2 > num1){ return num2 }
!if(num1 == num2){ return num1 }
!endfunction

!function $fixLen($name)
!$maxNum = $pmax($longestActivityLength,%strlen($name))
!return sprintf("%-*s%s%*s", maxNum / 2, 0), "", $name, ceiling(maxNum / 2, 0)), "")
!endfunction

skinparam swimlaneWidth same
|A|
:foo1;
:$fixLen("foo2");
|b|
:foo3 which is very long;
@enduml
```

and here is the error.

[image: error in preprocessing]

My guess is that this is a syntax error. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Doesn't `$pmax` have 2 arguments, in `$pmax($longestActivityLength - %strlen($name))` I see only one?

Comment: @albert I have changed this, i still get the same error.